# Antd Inline Form Width of Children

Tags: css, reactjs, forms, antd

I have a form that I would like to be inline with a select filling up the first 60% of space and the submit button filling up the next 40%.
I can't figure out how to do this without the select and the button sizing themselves incorrectly.
The select sizes itself to match its input, starting with almost no size.
The button takes on a size less than its text.
What are you supposed to do in this situation?

```
<Form layout="inline">
    <Form.Item style={{width:'60%'}}>
        {getFieldDecorator('studentId', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'You must select a student' }],
        })(
            <Select style={{width:'100%'}}>
                {this.props.linkedStudents.map(x => <Select.Option value={x.id}>{x.fullName}</Select.Option>)}
            </Select>
        )}
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item style={{width:'30%'}}>
    <Button
        type="primary"
        htmlType="submit"
        style={{ width: '30%' }}
    >
        Remove from Team
    </Button>
    </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle of this specific scenario.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to alter the `ant-form-item-control-wrapper` style. You can do it through `CSS` or through the `Form.Item`'s `wrapperCol` property.

For the below to work, you'll want to wrap the `Select`'s `Form.Item` in an element with a `className="select-container"`

```
.select-container.ant-form-item-control-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
```

or

`<Form.Item wrapperCol={{ sm: 24 }} style={{ width: "60%", marginRight: 0 }}>`

The `sm` refers the [column layout](https://ant.design/components/grid/#Col) and `24` refers to the [outline](https://ant.design/components/grid/#Outline).

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/w0voxxxzm5 (this assumes you don't want any gutter between the select and the button)

**components/InlineForm.js**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { Button, Form, Select } from "antd";
const { Item } = Form;
const { Option } = Select;

const students = [
  {
    id: 1,
    fullName: "Bob Smith"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    fullName: "Amber Johnson"
  }
];

class InlineForm extends PureComponent {
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 4));
      }
    });
  };

  render = () => {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;

    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} layout="inline">
        <Item
          wrapperCol={{ sm: 24 }}
          style={{ width: "60%", height: 60, marginBottom: 0, marginRight: 0 }}
        >
          {getFieldDecorator("studentId", {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: "You must select a student" }]
          })(
            <Select style={{ width: "100%" }}>
              {students.map(({ id, fullName }) => (
                <Option key={fullName} value={id}>
                  {fullName}
                </Option>
              ))}
            </Select>
          )}
        </Item>
        <Item wrapperCol={{ sm: 24 }} style={{ width: "40%", marginRight: 0 }}>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
            Register
          </Button>
        </Item>
      </Form>
    );
  };
}

export default Form.create({ name: "inline-form" })(InlineForm);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `style = {{width:" 60% "}}` worked for me, but in the end I preferred to use `style = {{flex: 1}}`, since in my case I was dividing the `<InlineForm/>` into 3 fields.

[Simplified hooks version](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-inlineform-childrenwidth-2cs9t?file=/index.js):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Button, Form, Select } from "antd";

const students = [
  { id: 1, fullName: "Bob Smith" },
  { id: 2, fullName: "Amber Johnson" }
];

const InlineForm = () => {
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} layout="inline">
      <Form.Item style={{ width: "60%", height: 90, margin: 0 }}>
        <Select style={{ width: "100%" }}>
          {students.map((student) => (
            <Select.Option key={student.id} value={student.id}>
              {student.fullName}
            </Select.Option>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item style={{ width: "40%", marginRight: 0 }}>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
          Register
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <div>
    App using InlineForm
    <br />
    <InlineForm />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```